# Convert CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1 from php to RSA Public key in Java

Tags: java, php, android, rsa, phpseclib

I'm trying to send a RSA Public Key from PHP to Java(Android). My PHP code looks something like this:

```
function __construct() {
        $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
        $rsa->setHash('sha1');
        $rsa->setMGFHash('sha1');
        $rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
        $rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1);
        $rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1);

        // Code to Generate the public key and private key

        $keys = $rsa->createKey(1024);

        extract($keys);

        // Base 64 encode Public and Private key
        $this->rsa = $rsa;
        $this->keys = $keys;
        $this->publicKeyBase = base64_encode($publickey);
        $this->privateKeyBase = base64_encode($privatekey);
}
```

And I send  `$this->publicKeyBase` to my Android app. In Java I get the encoded string like this:

`LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFVCTElDIEtFWS0tLS0tDQpNSUdKQW9HQkFMQzluUkdhVGsybzlJTW5YVW0vWWRVMHMrTFplc09GUi9VYkU2K21hWDlwbGIwRW11RzZacHBMDQpoV2dRbUNBYmV6aW9ScHZNL0lVZHZWczZ6ZmFKaDRGTnFaRXo0cWd0V0ovaFpUU2RudlFIMlI3cWF0TEY0c0ZSDQpDbWNNVDZBdnYvdDJnR1liMW4vY1lhb01ralNOd1RFdTJBSU45djg0Skk2ZWhmOGNST0RMQWdNQkFBRT0NCi0tLS0tRU5EIFJTQSBQVUJMSUMgS0VZLS0tLS0=`

And after decoding it, it looks something like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIGJAoGBALC9nRGaTk2o9IMnXUm/YdU0s+LZesOFR/UbE6+maX9plb0EmuG6ZppL
    hWgQmCAbezioRpvM/IUdvVs6zfaJh4FNqZEz4qgtWJ/hZTSdnvQH2R7qatLF4sFR
    CmcMT6Avv/t2gGYb1n/cYaoMkjSNwTEu2AIN9v84JI6ehf8cRODLAgMBAAE=
    -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

How do I convert this to a pubic key that can be used in the Android App. Have seen lots of examples online but they aren't working and my java code(below) also seems not to work. Any possible solutions?

```
private static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromPemFormat(String PEMString, boolean isFilePath) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException {

        BufferedReader pemReader = null;
        if (isFilePath) {
            pemReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(PEMString)));
        } else {
            pemReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(PEMString.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        }
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = pemReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf("-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----") != -1) {
                while ((line = pemReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.indexOf("-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----") != -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    content.append(line.trim());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (line == null) {
            throw new IOException("PUBLIC KEY" + " not found");
        }
        Log.i("PUBLIC KEY: ", "PEM content = : " + content.toString());

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(content.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT)));

    }
```

---

```
new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(content.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT)) throws an Invalid KeySpec Exception.
```

Comment: I don't know about your problem, but when you try to encrypt something, use the proper `Cipher` instance: `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding`

Comment: @ArtjomB. `new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(content.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT))` throws an Invalid KeySpec Exception

Comment: @GregS Thanks a lot! Your solution seemed to work, wish I could upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is a little confusing, but by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php) for method `_convertPublicKey($n, $e)` starting at line 950 it appears that if `$publicKeyFormat == PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS8` then the output format should be one that is compatible with Java's [X509EncodedKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html) class.